# How to get a list of the foreign key together with the index name on that foreign key?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am using this query to list all the foreign key, but I also need to have the index name on that foreign key.

```
select a.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as a
where a.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

How to get a list of the foreign key together with the index name on that foreign key?

Comment: Which index's name, index in the referenced or referencing table?

Comment: @Shadow Let's say I add a foreign key to a column in a table, but no index on a given column, thus an index is automatically created...  As for now, I want to get the list of foreign key and the index name too. How can I get this?